# Proof of closure, convex hull and minimal cone of dual set

Tags: inner-products, convex-geometry, dual-cone, convex-hulls, convex-cone

In my studies of convexity I have recently come across the following:

> Let $ V=\mathbb{R}^d ; d \geq 1 $ be a Euclidean space and $ S \neq \emptyset $ be a non empty set of the vector space $ V $, where we define its dual as usual 
>   $ S^* = \{y\in V | \forall x \in S ; \langle y,x \rangle \geq 0 \} $. Now I have already proved that $ S^* $ is always a closed convex cone, now I wish to prove the following: $ S^* = (\bar{S})^* = {(conv(S))}^*= {(cone(S))}^* $ where "conv" is the usual convex hull and "cone" is the minimal convex cone containing $S$ and $ \bar{S} $ is the closure of $S$.

I have proved that the dual set is always a closed convex cone, is there a way to prove these equalities I have written, I seem to be stuck on this. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $S$ has nonzero vector

Note that for $x\neq 0\in S$ $H_x:=\{ y|y\cdot x\geq 0\}$ is closed
half space That is $ S^\ast$ is intersection of these closed half
space Hence $S^\ast$ is closed convex In further closed half space
is cone so that $S^\ast$ is cone

(1) $S^\ast  =  (\overline{S})^\ast$ : From this argument we have
that
$$ S\subset \overline{S}\Rightarrow S^\ast \supseteq
(\overline{S})^\ast $$

If $x_n\in S$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$ let $$ v\in \bigcap_{n}
 H_{x_n} $$

so that $$ v\cdot x_n\geq 0 \Rightarrow v\cdot x\geq 0 $$

That is $v\in H_x$ so that $\bigcap_{n}
 H_{x_n} \subset H_x $

(2) $S^\ast =({\rm conv}\ S)^\ast$ : $x_i\in S$ then
$v:=\sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i\in {\rm conv}\ S$ where $c_i\geq 0,\ \sum_i
c_i=1$ Assume that $$w\in \bigcap_i H_{x_i}$$ Then
$$ w\cdot v =\sum_i c_ix_i\cdot w \geq 0\Rightarrow w\in H_v$$

(3) $({\rm conv}\ S)^\ast =({\rm cone}\ S)^\ast$ : For $v\in {\rm
cone}\ S$, we have $$ w\in {\rm conv}\ S,\ tw=v,\ t>0 $$

Hence $$ H_v=H_w$$